# Open a socket server over the internet with miniupnp

Tags: python, sockets, upnp

I am trying to open a server socket on a specific port forwarded by the library `miniupnpc`. The problem is that I can't reach my server from other external devices in any way. Here's the server.py:

```
from miniupnpc import UPnP
import socket

upnp = UPnP()

def forward_port(port_no):
    upnp.discoverdelay = 10
    upnp.discover()
    upnp.selectigd()
    upnp.addportmapping(port_no, 'TCP', upnp.lanaddr, port_no, ' ', '')


def close_port(port_no):
    upnp.deleteportmapping(port_no, 'TCP')


PORT = 6666

try:
    forward_port(PORT)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    print(s)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(addr, 'connected')
    conn.send(b'some response')
finally:
    close_port(PORT)
```

the client.py:

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('My public ip', 6666))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

the server prints out the socket element, but it never prints out the addr. The client got a timeout error.

Comment: What error you get both in server and client?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307622/6783775) help?

Comment: I Liju, I already told at the end of my question that the server never got any errors but continues to wait for connections, Client got a timeout error. Seems like the port was never got forwarded...

Comment: Hi rveerd, I will answer at every point of the answer you linked to me:
1) My client (always me) knows my static router IP.
2) As I already told ebove, I have a static IP.
3) I'm using miniupnpc to avoid to manually port forward into my router and as far as I've seen on the internet this works for everybody except me.
4) I do not have any active firewall.
5) I always check my IP address, it's always the same.