# How to use python socket on different networks

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, ipv6

I have been trying to send files using the ipv6 address but whenever I change my network it fails to connect here are both of the codes.
**CLIENT**

```
import os
import time
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
host = 'x' # ipv6 address
port = 5001
filename = input('File Name:')
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)

print(f"[+] Connecting to {host}:{port}")
s.connect((host, port,0,0))
print("[+] Connected.")

s.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    for _ in range(filesize):
        # read the bytes from the file
        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        s.sendall(bytes_read)
s.close()
```

**SERVER**

```
import socket
import time
import os
# device's IP address
SERVER_HOST = "::"
SERVER_PORT = 5001
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

client_socket, address = s.accept() 
print(f"[+] {address} is connected.")
received = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
filesize = int(filesize)
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    for _ in range(filesize):
        # read 1024 bytes from the socket (receive)
        bytes_read = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:    
            break
        f.write(bytes_read)
client_socket.close()
# close the server socket
s.close()
```

Thanks in advance.
I have literally just started learning python so I feel like I may need entire codes or youtube tutorial links.

Comment: "_whenever I change my network_". Well, then don't change your network :) What do you mean?  "_it fails to connect_". What error do you get?

Comment: The server is simply not found. I am trying to make a server that people can connect from anywhere. Also, I am new so please help me out with this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js, socket-io based one to one chat engine working fine on LOCAL but not working when running on different laptops using ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301083/node-js-socket-io-based-one-to-one-chat-engine-working-fine-on-local-but-not-wo)

Comment: Just solved the problem myself. But thanks for looking into my problem.