# how can i make my server script as an actual server from my pc for my group chat project

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.10

i build a chat app
it has a server script and a client script
i can only use the server locally
none of my friends can't join my application
i build it using python

this is from the server side

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
# do not take any reserved or well known ports
port = 55555

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()
```

and this is form the client site

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 55555))
```

now i want to host it so my friends can also join my room or my chat

i want to host using my pc

** HOW CAN I DO THAT **
[this is my github for my project u guys can check the server and the client](https://github.com/SamiulNahiyan/CIT_GROUP_CHAT.git)

Comment: You need to use a public IP address. 127.0.0.1 is the IP address usually called 'localhost', and is called a 'loopback' address because traffic sent to it never leaves the device it's send from, and can only be received in software running on that same device.

Comment: Also, you need to correctly configure your [network and router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307622/6783775).

Comment: You need to look up "port forwarding". No different than making your PC a minecraft server